How to Add Labels to API Calls for Anthropic Models using Vertex AI on GCloud?
I'm using Vertex AI on Google Cloud, where I know that it's possible to define labels for LLM requests via generateContent API calls, as described in this documentation: Custom metadata labels.
I am now looking to achieve the same functionality with calls to Anthropic models using the Anthropic SDK (npm package: @anthropic-ai/vertex-sdk). Does anyone know if it is possible to add labels to these API calls as well? If so, how can it be done?
